# Highstock when multiple lines share a y axis one line is drawn at an offset

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I am using Highstock/Highchart and if I draw two lines on a graph, who share a single Y axis, one of the lines isn't displayed on the Y axis properly. It is offset to higher values. For example, a value is 120 but the dot shows up on the 200 line. I would post a pic but I can't yet.

I have tried setting the Y axis max by the highest value but the line goes off the chart because it's still rendered with an offset.

Here is my config for the chart :

```
$scope.chartConfig = {
  options: {
    style: {
      fontSize: '12px'
    },
    chart: {
      alignTicks: true,
      type: 'spline'
    },
    rangeSelector: {
      inputEnabled: true, //$('#container').width() > 480,
      selected: 0,
      buttons: [{
        type: 'week',
        count: 1,
        text: '1w'
      },
      {
        type: 'month',
        count: 1,
        text: '1m'
      },
      {
        type: 'month',
        count: 3,
        text: '3m'
      }, {
        type: 'month',
        count: 6,
        text: '6m'
      }, {
        type: 'ytd',
        text: 'YTD'
      }, {
        type: 'year',
        count: 1,
        text: '1y'
      }, {
        type: 'all',
        text: 'All'
      }]
    },
    navigator: {
      enabled: true
    },
    tooltip: {
      animation: true,
      enabled: true,
      shadow: true,
      shared: false,
      useHTML: false,
      xDateFormat: '%m/%d/%Y'
    },
    colors: ['#51324e', '#6e6e6e', '#3d2b3b', '#515151', '#342d3d', '#3e3e3e', '#413451', '#4f4b4b', '#351032', '#3e3e3e'],
    plotOptions: {
      pointStart: 0,
      'line': {
        'cursor': 'pointer',
        'marker': {
          'lineWidth': 1.5,
        },
        'lineWidth': 1
      },
      column: {
        grouping: true
      },
      series: {
        stacking: 'normal',
      }
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
  },
  yAxis: {
    //min: 10,
    max: null,
    title: {
      text: ''
    }
  },
  stackLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    style: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    }
  },
  useHighStocks: true,
  series: [{
      //type: 'column',
      marker : {
        enabled : true,
        radius : 4,
        fillColor: {},
        lineColor: {},
        lineWidth: 3,
        symbol: 'diamond'
      },
      name: '',
      data: [[
        0,0
      ]],
      dataGrouping: {
        units: [[
          'week', // unit name
          [1] // allowed multiples
        ], [
          'month',
          [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
        ]]
      }
    },
    {
      //type: 'column',
      marker : {
        enabled : true,
        radius : 4,
        fillColor: {},
        lineColor: {},
        lineWidth: 3,
        symbol: 'diamond'
      },
      name: '',
      data: [[
        0,0
      ]],
      dataGrouping: {    // TODO: delete me?
        units: [[
          'week', // unit name
          [1]
        ], [
          'month',
          [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
        ]]
      }
    }
  ],
    title: {
      style: {
        color: '#51324e'
      }
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    }
  };
```

In the HTML:

```
<highchart id="chart" class="hiChart-container" config="chartConfig"></highchart>
```

And all I change is the data and series name to update the chart...
I am only importing Highstock and using Highchart-ng.
I cannot do var chart = new Chart($scope.chartConfig) because my javascript framework is AngularJS and hence we are using Highchart-ng

How do I adjust the lines to be scaled to the Y axis?

Comment: Have you live demo of it?